# IE: Page requires to be refreshed twice

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a javascript function that executes at page load, which is like this:

```
if (isTrue()) {
    $.post("check.php", { value: 'true' } );
} else {
    $.post("check.php", { value: 'false' } );   
}
```

check.php looks like this:

```
if ($_POST['value'] == 'true') { 
    $_SESSION['value'] = true;
} else {
    $_SESSION['value'] = false;
}
```

My problem is that if the function isTrue() is changed to return false, and I go to IE, I need to refresh the page twice to see that it was changed. If I set it to true again, same thing, when I refresh the first time changes are not there, when refreshing again, now they are.

What could be the cause of this odd thing?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: can you show us the isTrue function? I suspect it's not always returning the value you are expecting

Comment: It's just a dummy function. I just traced the javascript, and the javascript is working perfectly. It's because of the $_SESSION, sometimes $_SESSION['value'] is set after the content was loaded, that's why then in the second refresh it's fine.

Comment: Pages fetched with POST are never cached, so the cache and ifModified options in jQuery.ajaxSetup() have no effect on these requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the $_SESSION, $_SESSION['value'] is set but you don't see that result until you refresh again, because the page was already loaded using the old value.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some kind of caching problem?
Try clearing your browsers cache after the change and see, if you still need a second refresh.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the result of jQuery AJAX caching. I've had similar problems myself.

Try turning it off with this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "check.php",
    data: { value: 'true' },
    cache: false
});
```

Also try fiddling the requests to check whether they're actually being made or not to confirm that it's a caching issue.